# Changes to text file with php and ajax-driven form

Tags: php, html

i have created a simple html form with one field and it post to the server side php and the value of the field is saved to a text file.

This is the parts of the code:

Html:

```
<form action="videorefresh.php" method="POST">
    <input name="videolink" type="text" size="70" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php

$open = fopen("video.txt","w+");
$txt = "video.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['videolink'])) { // check if both fields are set
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
    $txt=$_POST['videolink']; 
    fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
}

?>
```

here everythink works fine!

I want to drive all this through Ajax so the main html form wont refresh.

so here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./JS/videolink.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainform">
  <div id="form">
    <div>
      <input name="videolink" type="text" id="videolink" size="70">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var name = $("#videolink").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'videolink1='+ videolink ;
if(videolink=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./videorefresh.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

What i do wrong here and it doesnt work?

Please help

Comment: `url: "./videorefresh.php"` is wrong. Try `/videorefresh.php` or `videorefresh.php`

Comment: Also you send `videolink1` using `$_POST['videolink']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do is:

```
var dataString = '?videolink='+ name;//typo videolink
// or better put an id on the form and use serialize()
// var dataString = $('#myform).serialize();
```

NOT

```
var dataString = 'videolink1='+ videolink ;
```

You have the value of the input in name, videolink is undefined